# How to construct a correct type transformation in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

In order to map from a constructed type `tainted_value` to other types, and from other basic types to the constructed type `tainted_value`, there are two functions constructed.

First, the type `tainted_value` is defined as:

```
type object_ = int 
and location = Obj of object_ | Null
and closure = var * cmd * stack
and value = Fld of string | Int of int | Loc of location | Clo of closure
and tainted_value = Val of value | Error
```

If I just let my first function mapping from `tainted_value` to `string` look like:

```
let tva_to_string tva1 = match tva1 with 
  | Val (Fld e) -> e 
  | _ -> None
```

It reports error as:

```
This expression has type 'a option but an expression was expected of type string
```

However, it will not return error if I change `None` into `failwith "Empty"`:

```
let tva_to_string tva1 = match tva1 with
  | Val (Fld e) -> e 
  | _ -> failwith "Empty"
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`None` is a constructor for the `option` type. If one clause in a `match` returns `None` then the others must return some other value of type `option`. They may also raise an exception, which is what the `failwith` function does.

The other constructor for `option` is `Some`, so you may be looking for:

```
let tva_to_string tva1 = match tva1 with 
  | Val (Fld e) -> Some e 
  | _ -> None
```

This will alleviate your type-checking issues. Of course, it still doesn't return a `string` so your naming of the function either needs some work, or you need to return strings.